# Why can't I redirect www to non-www on my addon domain?

Tags: domains, htaccess, apache, subdomain, add-on-domain

I have a domain *example.com* in which I'm doing this to redirect all my traffic from www version to non-www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything fine until now. I can do www.example.com to example.com,  but I also have another domain which I am hosting on the same account as a addon domain. Like there is a folder like *example.org* in my base www directory of example.com.

Now when I'm doing www.example.org, I get `http://example.com/example.org` with an additional 404.

Hope you get my point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because the `.htaccess` will be inherited in all child directories. This is a common issue when using add-on domains because each domain shares the same path environment.

This can be resolved by any of the following:

- Use more secure hosting with jailed accounts
- Use a `.htaccess` in each add-on domain child directory
- Use `%{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.example.com [NC]` rather than `%{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]`

Comment: I opt to go for third one. :D

Comment: Just a note on the "Use a .htaccess in each add-on domain child directory" - you would also need to (at least) enable the rewrite engine (ie. `RewriteEngine On`) in the child directory's .htaccess file in order to prevent the parent mod_rewrite directives being "inherited".